# How-to: Proper redirect with Relative URLs ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, redirect

I have an authentication script (**`CheckLogin.aspx`**), and if any of the credentials do not match my application will redirect (via **`Server.Transfer`**) to the access denied page (**`forbidden.aspx`**).  Each time my script runs,it gets an **`InvalidOperationException: Failed to map the path '/forbidden.aspx'`**.  Here is a mockup of my applications file structure:

```
<root>
..default.aspx
..forbidden.aspx
..<inc>
....scripts.js
..<auth>
....CheckLogin.aspx
```

As you can see, the **`CheckLogin.aspx`** page is in a folder inside the root, and the **`forbidden.aspx`** page is inside the root itself.  The path I am telling my application to redirect to is **`/forbidden.aspx`**.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sometimes you have to precede the page path with a tilde to indicate the root directory:

```
'~/forbidden.aspx'
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you using "~/..."  to make sure all your paths are relative?

By the way, you should just set up page access via Web.config, by using the `<location>` tags.  That way you can have some sort of role-based access, without much custom code.

Comment: The reason I am using this method is my webapp links with a platform application that communicate together.